# How to ensure that finish() destroy activity and clear all variables?

Tags: android

I'm working in a project with two activities, one shows list of rows from a database, when you click one it opens other activity with a form containing elements you can edit;

The problem is that when i close the second activity and reopen it (even if I call `finish()`) some variables keep data from last "session".

So may question is: How can I clear all variables/destroy activity?

EDIT

As I keep reading and trying I still cant figure out the real problem so there are some extra info:

-Custom controllers I'm using

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

    private boolean edited=false;
    private boolean init;
    private boolean justLoad;
    private String oldText;
    public boolean required;

    public boolean isEdited() {
        return edited;
    }

    public String getOldText() {
        return oldText;
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);
        if (justLoad) {
            edited=false;
            justLoad=false;
        } else {
            String currtext = this.getText().toString();
            if (!init) {
                oldText = currtext;
                init = true;
            }
            if (!currtext.equals(oldText)) {
                edited = true;
            } else {
                edited = false;
            }
        }
        Log.d("cet",this.getText().toString()+" != "+oldText+" "+edited);
    }

    public void load(String text){
        init=true;
        oldText=text;
        edited=false;
        justLoad=true;
        this.setText(text);
    }
}
```

-Utility class(also tried non-static

```
public class CustomViewUtilities {

    private static boolean edited=false;
    private static  ArrayList<EditText> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public  static boolean isAnyEdited(ViewGroup view){
        CustomViewUtilities c = new CustomViewUtilities();
        c.traverseEditTexts(view);
        return edited;
    }

    public static ArrayList<EditText> getList(ViewGroup view) {
        list.clear();
        CustomViewUtilities c = new CustomViewUtilities();
        c.traverseEditTexts(view);
        return list;
    }

    private EditText traverseEditTexts(ViewGroup v)
    {
        EditText invalid = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < v.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            Object child = v.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof EditText)
            {
                EditText e = (EditText)child;
                if (e instanceof CustomAutoCompleteTextView){
                    list.add(e);

                    if (((CustomAutoCompleteTextView) e).isEdited()) {
                        edited = true;}
                } else if (e instanceof CustomEditText) {
                    if (((CustomEditText) e).isEdited()) {
                        edited = true;}
                    list.add(e);
                }
            }
            else if(child instanceof ViewGroup)
            {
                invalid = traverseEditTexts((ViewGroup)child);  // Recursive call.
                if(invalid != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return invalid;
    }
}
```

I also tried to change `android:launchMode` with no result.
The issue is that the second time I launch activity if the `CustomViewUtilities.isAnyEdited(view);` method returns true any time it will return true next time that activity launches.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you dont need to finish your activity.. use setNotifyDataChange on adepter

Comment: read about `<activity android:launchMode />`

Comment: set launchMode to standard may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the problem was nothing to do with android, the actual problem was `CustomViewUtilities.edited;` witch originally was instantiated each time `private boolean edited=false;` was turned to static `private static boolean edited=false;` so it never back to false and never get destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

Override the `onDestroy()` method and in this method Just call `finish()` and `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` methods...

All variables must be assigned `NULL`...

My code:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try{
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        finish();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should not happen if you kept all the data in your activity. If you read the data from outside of Activity (Application class, directly from database  or SharedPrefs maybe) it would stay as it is.

If that is not the case my suggestion would be to create something like this:

```
private void invalidateData(){
// invalidate all relevant fields (set as null or 0)
}
```

Call this method on activity onDestroy method

Answer (score 1):

Consider the documentation invoking finish method does not garantee immediate destroying.
But for your situation you can override onPause method. It invokes automatically when activity become hidden. If you will use this you have to initialize data in onResume method.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // init data here
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // destroy data here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yourExistingActivity.finish();  // This **requests** for freeing the memory
```

Note that the activity you're calling the finish() method from is destroyed and ALL its resources are **queued** for garbage collection, and all memory that was used by this activity will be freed during **next GC cycle**.

If you really want to revoke the memory as soon as possible, override your activities' onDestroy method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();      //This is the key
}
```